# How to invoke JQuery method dynamically on changing Tree structure in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to build Tree by using `angularjs`.

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZ5qF/77/).

The code works but my problem is:

When I try to add new node after 5 sec, Jquery method doesn't work for added node. All other work fine.

This is my method I want to invoke:

```
$(function () {
$('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');
$('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function (e) {
    var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
    if (children.is(":visible")) {
        children.hide('fast');
        $(this).attr('title', 'Expand this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-plus-sign').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
    } else {
        children.show('fast');
        $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-minus-sign').removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
});
```

**How can I invoke Jquery style (add/remove class) dynamically?**

Let me know if you want to put code from Fiddler to there.

Thank you,

*By the way, this example will be helpful (how to build tree with angularjs)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated "you have no time to implement in Angular right now", you could grab all jQuery code, put inside a directive linking function and use this directive in every `li` element. You should change your selectors too. Something like this:

```js
angular.module('module', []).directive('treeNode', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
      if (elm.find('ul').length) {
        elm.addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');
        elm.find('> span').on('click', function (e) {
          // your current code, changed as we did previously
        });
      } 
    }
  }
});
```

And you should decorate all your `<li ng-repeat="..." tree-node>`. You can remove the initialization code after that.

Just be sure to load jQuery lib before loading Angular.

Disclaimer: **this is not the preferred way**, you should rewrite it as I told in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17833690/179138.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`ng-class`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass) for dynamic classing and [`ng-click`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClick) for click handling.

For your class binding, you can go with:

```html
<li ng-class="{'icon-plus-sign': show, 'icon-minus-sign': !show}">
```

For the title attribute, you can simple use a binding:

```html
<li title="{{show && 'Expand' || 'Collapse'}}" ...>
```

At last, in your scope, you need a click handling that receives the current clicked node:

```js
$scope.clicked = function(node) {
  node.show = !node.show;
}
```

and in your binding:

```html
<li ng-click="clicked(item)">
```

Note I'm considering that `show` property is reflecting if the node is either opened or collapsed. Also, just to be sure, `item` in the `ng-click` comes from the `ng-repeat` expression.

Comment: How can you define `item`, `ng-model="item"` in `<span>`?

Comment: No. Sorry, you're using `data`. In your `ng-repeat` you have `ng-repeat="data in fullTree`. You can use `ng-click="clicked(data)"`. You probably need to change some more things in your code, but following this line, you will get what you need.

Comment: Sure, the best way to remove all JQuery, I don't like it but right now dont hav etime to implement the same in angularjs